# Loop for smooth cube size increasing

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

How to code a cube increasing program like this:

`transform.localScale = new Vector3(5, 5, 5);`

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class CountDown : MonoBehaviour
{

public float leftTime;
private Text timerText;

void Start()
{
    timerText = GetComponent<Text>();
}
void Update()
{
    leftTime -= Time.deltaTime;
    timerText.text = leftTime.ToString("f0");
}
```

1. There is a 5s countdown
2. Cube starts with his starting scales.
3. Cube size increases 5s. Like 1 second = 1 more cordinate to every
   scale.
4. It works smoothly.

I imagine how to make it, but something not working and I can't make it.

Facts:

- Game is 2D
- I am using c#, but I know a bit of javascript too.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, if you tried anything and faced any problem then post here for help

Comment: I can't see your code. Can you please tell me the cheat-code to read the full question?

Comment: I added code @UmairM

Comment: OK! why do you have multiple `while` loops? And you code tells me that you are trying to do a kind of animation (scale up and scale down in given time). I would suggest you to use [Animation system](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/animation) instead. It will be a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

You should start with asking yourself the question more appropriately. That is "How can I animate my cube over time?". Now you already have half of the answer in the question. At least in my opinion.

You should look into Animation and Animator. This will provide full control over change of values over time.

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/animation/animator-controller

On top of that, less code and less code is less possible bugs.